# Method of Characteristics Quasilinear

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have the following quasilinear PDE

$h_t - 3(1-h)^2 \sin \theta h_\theta = -(1-h)^3 \cos \theta$

and we wish to solve it via the method of characteristics.

We have

$h_s = -(1-h)$ with $h(0) = h_0 \Rightarrow$ $h = 1 - e^s + h_0 e^s$

$\theta_s = -3 \tan \theta$ with $\theta(0) = \theta_0 \Rightarrow \theta = \arcsin\left(e^{-3s}\sin \theta_0\right)$

$t_s = \frac{1}{(1-h)^2 \cos \theta} = \frac{1}{e^{2s}(1-h_0)^2\sqrt{1-e^{-6s}\sin \theta_0}}$ gives

$t = f(\theta_0)  -\frac{e^{4 s} \csc ^2(\text{$\theta_0$}) \sqrt{1-e^{-6 s} \sin ^2(\text{$\theta_0$})} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},1;\frac{7}{6};e^{6 s} \csc ^2(\text{$\theta_0$})\right)}{(h_0-1)^2}$

Rewriting in terms of $h$ and $\theta$ gives

$t = f\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{(h-1)^3 \sin (\theta )}{(h_0-1)^3}\right)\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\cos ^2(\theta )} \csc ^2(\theta ) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},1;\frac{7}{6};\csc ^2(\theta )\right)}{(h-1)^2}$

I now wish to get an expression with some initial conditions say $h_0 = 0.8$ and $\theta_0 = 0.7$ but am unsure how to proceed. My worry is that, if we just take the Hypergeometric part and input some values of $\theta$ we get a complex number over $(h-1)^2$. I am motivated as the denominator looks correct (I believe I should get something like $h \sim 1- t^{-1/2}$).

But obviously the numerator needs to be real and it isn't for values of $\theta$ that in a full simulation clearly give a real answer

Attached is image of full simulation with $h_0 = 0.8$ at $\theta_0 = 0.7$, which asymptotes to 1.I would like to get an expression for this from what I have solved with the Hypergeometric function. Does anyone have any pointers?

[image]